# Different results between step debugging and running program on tiva c

Tags: c, arm, embedded, accelerometer, i2c

I have a TIVA tm4c123G I have been trying to create a communication between it and my ADXL345 sensor using I2C protocol which I succeeded in writing and reading from the accelerometer the readings of the device address and the register values that I just wrote to which means everything is running fine. However I have tried this in step by step debugging in keil and it works fine but if I run the program it will give zeroes all the way and I have no idea why? Should I add delays between the write and read from registers or whats going wrong in my code?

Here is my code attached
I am using a clock of 80 MHZ for the system and I think this might be the problem however as the code goes too fast to the execution of a next send and there should be some delay? I am not sure I'm only guessing please help thanks !

also my connection for the adxl is

1. Vcc  -> 3.3 volts
2. GND -> ground
3. CS -> 3.3 volts
4. SDO -> ground
5. SDA -> PB3
6. SCL -> PB2

---

```
#include "tm4c123gh6pm.h"
#include "stdint.h"

void EnableI2CModule0(void);
uint8_t ReadRegister(uint8_t RegisterAddress);
void PLL_Init(void);
void WriteRegister(uint8_t RegisterAddress,uint8_t Data);
volatile uint8_t X_Axis1,X_Axis2,Y_Axis1,Y_Axis2,Z_Axis1,Z_Axis2=0;

int main()  
{
    volatile long temp;
    PLL_Init();
    EnableI2CModule0();
    temp=ReadRegister(0x00);
    WriteRegister(0x2D,0x08);
    temp=ReadRegister(0x2D);
    WriteRegister(0x31,0x0B);
    temp=ReadRegister(0x31);    
    while(1)
    {
        X_Axis1=ReadRegister(0x32);
        X_Axis2=ReadRegister(0x33);
        Y_Axis1=ReadRegister(0x34);
        Y_Axis2=ReadRegister(0x35);
        Z_Axis1=ReadRegister(0x36);
        Z_Axis2=ReadRegister(0x37);
    }
}

void PLL_Init(void){
    // 0) Use RCC2
    SYSCTL_RCC2_R |=  0x80000000;  // USERCC2
    // 1) bypass PLL while initializing
    SYSCTL_RCC2_R |=  0x00000800;  // BYPASS2, PLL bypass
    // 2) select the crystal value and oscillator source
    SYSCTL_RCC_R = (SYSCTL_RCC_R &~0x000007C0)   // clear XTAL field, bits 10-6
                                 + 0x00000540;   // 10101, configure for 16 MHz crystal
    SYSCTL_RCC2_R &= ~0x00000070;  // configure for main oscillator source
    // 3) activate PLL by clearing PWRDN
    SYSCTL_RCC2_R &= ~0x00002000;
    // 4) set the desired system divider
    SYSCTL_RCC2_R |= 0x40000000;   // use 400 MHz PLL
    SYSCTL_RCC2_R = (SYSCTL_RCC2_R&~ 0x1FC00000)  // clear system clock divider
                                    + (4<<22);      // configure for 80 MHz clock
    // 5) wait for the PLL to lock by polling PLLLRIS
    while((SYSCTL_RIS_R&0x00000040)==0){};  // wait for PLLRIS bit
    // 6) enable use of PLL by clearing BYPASS
    SYSCTL_RCC2_R &= ~0x00000800;
}

void EnableI2CModule0(void)
{
    volatile int Delay=0;
    SYSCTL_RCGCI2C_R|=0x00000001; //set i2c module 0 clock active
    Delay=SYSCTL_RCGCI2C_R; //delay allow clock to stabilize 
    SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R |=0x00000002; //i2c module 0 is portB so activate clock for port B
    Delay = SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO_R; //delay allow clock to stabilize 
    GPIO_PORTB_AFSEL_R|= 0x0000000C; //enable alternate functions for PB2 and PB3
    GPIO_PORTB_ODR_R |= 0x00000008; //set PB3 (I2C SDA)  for open drain
    GPIO_PORTB_DEN_R |= 0xFF; //Enable digital on Port B
    GPIO_PORTB_PCTL_R |=0x03;
    I2C0_PP_R |= 0x01;
    I2C0_MTPR_R |= 0x00000027; //set SCL clock
    I2C0_MCR_R |= 0x00000010; //intialize mcr rigester with that value given in datasheet
}

uint8_t ReadRegister(uint8_t RegisterAddress)
{
    volatile uint8_t result=0;
    I2C0_MSA_R = 0x000000A6; //write operation
    I2C0_MDR_R = RegisterAddress; //place data to send mdr register
    I2C0_MCS_R = 0x00000007; //stop start run
    while((I2C0_MCS_R &= 0x00000040)==1); //poll busy bit 
    I2C0_MSA_R = 0x000000A7; // read operation
    I2C0_MCS_R = 0x00000007; // stop start run
    while((I2C0_MCS_R &= 0x00000040)==1); //poll busy bit 
    result = I2C0_MDR_R;
    return result;
}

void WriteRegister(uint8_t RegisterAddress,uint8_t Data)
{
    I2C0_MSA_R = 0x000000A6; //write operation
    I2C0_MDR_R = RegisterAddress; //place register address to set in mdr register
    I2C0_MCS_R = 0x00000003; //burst send ( multiple bytes send ) 
    while((I2C0_MCS_R &= 0x00000040)==1); //poll busy bit 
    I2C0_MDR_R = Data; //place data to be sent in  mdr register
    I2C0_MCS_R = 0x00000005; // transmit followed by stop state 
    while((I2C0_MCS_R &= 0x00000040)==1); //poll busy bit 
}
```

Comment: sorry for the indentation issues but the website was lagging for me for some reason , i hate it as well .

Comment: update , tried adding some delays between read and write register operations still give zeroes on reads , and still on step by step debugging give correct results

Comment: @MarkYisri excuse me but can u illustrate more on how off topic , un related or which part doesn't give clear information ?
also i am not asking you to solve my I2C problem i just need someone he is more expert than me in microcontrollers to tell me whats going on wrong , my I2C is working fine as the reading is done fine in step by step debugging in case you didn't read the original post :) but thank you for your help

Comment: We're not here to solve why I2C is reading 0. Read the data sheet.

Comment: clearley you still haven't read my post ... reading and writing is done PERFECTLY FINE in step by step debugging , I2C reads PERFECTLY FINE and works PERFECTLY FINE if i step by step debug , however if i RUN the code it DOESNT READ CORRECTLY

Comment: Reduce the clock speed.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "step-by-step"; are you stepping *over* the `ReadRegister`/`WriteRegister` functions or stepping  *into* them. If you *step over*, then the `ReadRegister`/`WriteRegister` functions themselves will run at full speed - whether that works or not may help narrow down the issue to one of either I2C interface peripheral timing or I2C device timing.  Ultimately an oscilloscope or I2C bus analyser may be the best way to see what is happening.

Comment: @MarkYisri : Then MTPR register value and 80MHz system clock suggests the I2C clock rate is 100KHz which is correct and supported by the ADXL345.

Comment: The so-called delays in `EnableI2CModule0()` are not much of a delay other then the time it takes to read the specific SYSCTL registers. The TM4C123G user manual however says nothing about needing to wait for clock stabilisation.  Since it is simply gating an stable system clock, it seems somewhat unnecessary in any case.  I doubt that it does anything useful.

Comment: In `EnableI2CModule0()` you have `I2C0_MTPR_R |= 0x00000027; //set SCL clock`; that should surely be `I2C0_MTPR_R = 0x00000027; //set SCL clock` (i.e. you set it to 39 not mask it with 39)?  The reset value for this register is 0x01, so you happen to be setting t to 39 in any case.  Since it is an arithmetic integer value rather than a bit field I'd use decimal rather then hex also.

Comment: @Clifford it doesnt say in the manual that it is needed but sometimes it really screws up if that delay isn't there , it's basically there to let the clock stabilize

Comment: @EssamEid : Perhaps it is necessary, but not for the reason you suggest - the clock is as I said already stable; the RGC simply gates an already running clock to the peripheral.  The peripheral perhaps needs to see the first clock edge before it is correctly running.  In the case of the I2C, the peripheral is not actually accessed until several instructions after the gate enable, so one wonders if that is necessary and is in any case a simple NOP would suffice?  At least perhaps cite the errata of app note that recommends that specific action in the comment, lest it gets removed in maintenance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @Clifford had explained that i should follow the flow charts and although his answer is completely correct it didn't give me any results (previously gave values in case of stepping into the function gave zeroes afterwards) but , i noticed something in the flow charts that i hadn't noticed before which contradicts with the initialization and configuration section in the data sheet

[image: initialization and configuration from the datasheet]

now as it says in step 11 that you should be polling the bus busy bit in the MCS register but this is wrong and contradicts with the flow charts , the flow charts are more correct as u should check if the bus is busy before sending anything and then check for the master busy bit before reading from the MDR register or moving on to execute and further steps

basically the correct steps in the initialization and configuration should be :
before step 10 poll the bus busy bit in case any other master is sending which can be omitted in case of a single master

after step 10 poll the busy bit before reading or going to any further step to conclude whether the sending has been completed and the master is idle or not

i'm sorry i feel like a complete idiot now for not reading the flow charts carefully but i followed another part which is the initialization and configuration part accepting a fact which wasn't there that both should imply the same thing .

i also found that it works correctly in the tivaware API following the flow charts and not that other section in the datasheet however i didn't want to use the Tivaware API as i am looking forward for problems like this which lead to a better understanding of how things work

thanks again for your help @Clifford cheers!

Comment: the final code should be replacing the bit to check instead of 0x00000040 on the MCS register should be 0x00000001 which is the busy bit instead of the bus busy bit

Comment: Posting a thorough description of the solution to you own question is very community spirited - good work.

Comment: i have had so much trouble to find an actual solution , everyone just says use tivaware and be done with it but i dont wanna take the easy way , hard way always helps you get a better understanding of things and who knows this might actually help someone in the future :D thanks you too for your help if it weren't for your flow charts i would have never found the solution actually :D

Answer (score 2):

Your `WriteRegister` and `ReadRegister` functions do not follow the flowcharts defined in the TM4C123G data sheet.  Apart from not checking or handling the MCS ERROR flag, Figure 16-10 *Master TRANSMIT of Multiple Data Bytes* shows that when writing the MCS register, you should assert specific bits, while you are writing to *all* bits, You should instead perform a read-modify-write:

```
I2C0_MCS_R = 0x00000003; //burst send ( multiple bytes send )
```

should be:

```
// I2CMCS = ---0-011
uint32_t mcs = I2C0_MCS_R ;
msc &= ~0x00000014; // ---0-0-- 
mcs |= 0x00000003;  // ------11
I2C0_MCS_R = mcs ;
```

And similarly:

```
I2C0_MCS_R = 0x00000005; // transmit followed by stop state
```

should be

```
// I2CMCS = ---0-101
mcs = I2C0_MCS_R ;
mcs &= ~0x00000012; // ---0--0- 
mcs |= 0x00000005;  // -----1-1
I2C0_MCS_R = mcs ;
```

[image]

`ReadRegister()` has a similar issue (although it is unlikely to be an issue in this case):

```
I2C0_MCS_R = 0x00000007; //stop start run
```

should *strictly* be:

```
// I2CMCS = ---00111
uint32_t mcs = I2C0_MCS_R ;
mcs &= ~0x00000018; // ---00--- 
mcs |= 0x00000007;  // -----111
I2C0_MCS_R = mcs ;
```

The datasheet recommends for bits 31:5:

> Software should not rely on the value of a reserved bit. To provide
>   compatibility with future products, the value of a reserved bit should
>   be preserved across a read-modify-write operation.

The above code does that, but in practice should not be necessary on this specific product, but is good practice in any case.

[image]

In any event you should add the recommended error handling code.  It may be that no error flag is being set, but we don't know that unless you check for it, and doing so will at least assist debugging - rather then stepping the code, you can simply set a break-point on the error handling and then run at full-speed.  This will narrow down the number of possibilities.

Comment: correct in everything you said except it didnt fix it when trying the method you provided it didnt give any reading although your method as i see it is more correct even in step by step which used to work
also by step by step i mean " stepping into the read function and write functions " i'm sorry i didn't clarify that earlier .
i found the fix from the flow charts you just showed i re read them carefully and there is a mistake in the initialization and configuration in the datasheet i have no idea how this is possible but this is the second mistake i find in the datasheet so far